# Using javascript in a hta file

Tags: javascript, html, hta

I have a html code and it has a js file inserted.
The javascript file is used with the inputs so i don't wanna remove the .js

Can i make this html file .hta? (html application?)

Is it possible to transform it to a .hta without removing the major parts?

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Search Engine</title>
    <style>
        div {
            background-color: lightgrey;
            height: 130px;
            width: 600px;
            border: 15px solid black;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="myClear()">
    <center>
        <input type="file" id="fileinput" /><br /><br />
        <input type="text" id="myInput" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mySE.js">        </script>
        <input type="submit" id="myClear"  value="Clear" onclick="myClear()" /><br /><br />
        <div id="fxQU" class="fxQU"></div>
    </center>
    <p id="myQU"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the JS file content as well please?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use JavaScript in a .hta and you can reference separate javascript files in the normal way.

As a bonus, you can even instantiate ActiveX objects using javascript if you need to (which you can't do in a normal browser). I once wrote a HTA which used JavaScript to talk to an Oracle database via ODBC (via ActiveX).

Comment: The problem is when i run this code in html it works flawless. But when i do so in Hta a window pops up giving me script error line 21 char 1 which is a document.getelementby id command

Comment: can you post the js file contents to the question?